# Undefined refernece when compiling a single file with g++

Tags: string, c++11, compilation, linker, g++

Whenever I compile my code, g++ returns this error message (this is just a segement. The rest is more of the same):

```
text.cpp:(.text+0x2b82): undefined reference to `parser(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/tmp/ccSFOyBc.o:text.cpp:(.text+0x2c3c): more undefined references to `parser(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' follow
/tmp/ccSFOyBc.o: In function `main':
text.cpp:(.text+0x2f02): undefined reference to `contains(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
text.cpp:(.text+0x30d2): undefined reference to `contains(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
```

Parser and contains are both functions I created that exist in the program. I heard this issue occurs when you do not link libraries or forgetting to link multiple files together, but I am only using one file (text.cpp) and have one library (-lncurses), and these errors occur with functions I have defined in the program.

I compile with `g++ text.cpp -lncurses`. I am using Fedora Linux 24 with the latest g++.

Snippet:
Functions in question:

```
void fight(vector<string> *i);
bool contains(vector<string> *v, string s);
bool parser(int a, string s);
void printinventory(vector<string> *i);
```

Contains:

```
   bool contains(vector<string> v, string s)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if(v.at(i)==s)
        {
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Function Calls (Both parser and contains are referenced in the first two lines of the error output at this location):

```
if(parser(6, stringinput) && contains(inventory, "Planck Plank") && currx == 0 && curry == 1 && currz == 2 && !planklaids) {
```

Any idea what this means?

Comment: It will be difficult to help without seeing your code.

Comment: I added some code. I tried a different version of g++, but no change.

Comment: Found it. Contains needs to be: 

bool contains(vector<string> *v, string s)

Answer (score 0):

I reference `bool contains(vector<string> *v, string s);` at the top but my function    `bool contains(vector<string> v, string s)` does not take a pointer variable. Code was fixed when I made my function at the bottom have the parameters indicated at the top.